# LVM volumes not present when linux start

Tags: ubuntu, lvm

We have a VMware cluster with 2 hypervisors, named as ESX6 and ESX7, the past Thursday we made a  hypervisor fail drill. We shutdown ESX6, we unplugged the cable.

All virtual machines starting to go up in ESX7 with no apparent problems, we reviewed the servers and all was working in 4 minutes, nice.

However, we noticed that we couldn't access to our Zabbix server, we accessed to the console from vCenter and we saw that there was a problem.

SZabbix (our VM with Zabbix server) start but it hangs on `initramfs starting`.
SZabbix has an Ubuntu 22.04.1 and it hangs on starting, appear this message:

```
[       1.558209] Run /init as init process
initramfs: Waiting for /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv to appear ...
```

After several minutes ...

```
[       1.558209] Run /init as init process
initramfs: Waiting for /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv to appear ...
initramfs: Timeout while waiting for devices for / (and possibly /usr) filesistems to appear (did you specify the correct ones?)
initramfs: Will cause kernel panic in 10s...
```

And after 10 seconds it hangs with kernel panic.

We started to think that it was something related to the drill, so we restored a backup from previous days, we were surprised that the problem persists, and we started to think that the problem was there but the server had not restarted and that's why had not occurred...

We don't know what to think honestly...

Well, I have boot using a Live Ubuntu and I can see that we have:

- sda2 with boot information (kernel and grub files)
- sda3 is a partition with LVM volumes

I can access to files through `/dev/dm-0` or `/dev/mapper/vg-ubuntu/lv-ubuntu` or `/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv`, I can mount the file system and access to the files, we have check the file system with `fsck` and all is ok I don't know what to think.

I have try with `boot-repair` tool and nothing, it says to have restored grub and all but the problem persist.

It seems that when Initramfs starts the LVM volumes are not loaded and that is why it cannot boot.

**MORE DATA**

pvdisplay shows:

[image: pvdisplay]

lvdisplay shows:

[image: lvdisplay]

vgdisplay shows:

[image: vgdisplay]

**UPDATE 1**

Ubuntu was using 5.15.0-91-generic kernel, I have starting with a Ubuntu Desktop Live from CD, I have mount boot partition (sda2). Have copy vmlinuz-6.2.0-26-generic to this partition and I have generated a initramfs image using "mkinitramfs". After this I have added an option to GRUB called "Ubuntu kernel 6" and loading vmlinuz-6.2.0-26-generic and using intramfs image.

The system boot now but it stops the boot saying: "A start job is running for /dev/disk/by-uuid/XXXXXXXX", after time out it says:

```
[ TIME ] Time out waiting for device /dev/disk/by-uuid/XXXXX
[DEPEND] Dependecy failed for /boot
[DEPEND] Dependecy failed for Unattended Upgrades Shotdown
[DEPEND] Dependecy failed for Local FileSystems.
[DEPEND] Dependecy failed for File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/XXXX
....
....

You are in emergency mode. After logging in, type "journalctl -cb" to view systems logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or "exit" to boot into default mode.
Press Enter for maintenance
(or press COntrol-D to continue):
```

Now I don't know how to continue ...

**UPDATE 2**

Starting with kernel 6 and comment the fstab line when /boot is mounted, the system starts but network not working ...

**UPDATE 3**

We could to restore a old backup (august-2023) of this machine and it works. I can access to both machines, how to see the differencies?

Can I do something?

The result of pvdisplay, lvdisplay, vgdisplay and blkid in both machines is the same.

Comment: from your livecd, please run the lvm display commands (`pvdisplay`, `lvdisplay`, `vgdisplay`) and `blkid` and show the output.

Comment: Added results from commands

Comment: Is the `lvm2` package installed properly? It also contains the hooks and scripts in `/usr/share/initramfs-tools` to include the necessary lvm2 files into the initramfs.

Comment: As I know is installed propertly, it was working during months

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly why but it seems your LVM volume group is not "registered" as to be part of current system (maybe due a switch of hard drive).

I advice you to follow these commands well explained to reimport the volume :

https://tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/recipemovevgtonewsys.html

Also, thi may be an issue with a missing entry point in the fstab, then try to go in single mode, edit the fstab and find out what's missing or useless, comment it or add the one missing and then reboot. This should do the trick.

Comment: Nothing ... I have deactivated, exported, imported and ativated but not working... I have commented all fstab lines.